# Phing can't find composer.phar on MAMP Pro, OSX

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, phing, mamp-pro

Phing doesn't seem to be able run Composer using the  tag/command. It seems to look for composer.phar in the current directory. Since it's not executing composer.phar as a command and instead passing the string 'composer.phar' to the php binary, it can't use the system path to find composer.phar (unless I'm wrong?)

How do I make Phing run composer properly without explicitly telling it where composer.phar is? I don't want to do that because this build script should run on any system that has Composer and Phing installed.

My project has a build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="my-awesome-app" default="build" basedir=".">
    <target name="build">
        <composer command="install"></composer>
    </target>
</project>
```

I am running PHP through MAMP Pro on OSX so all the PHP related scripts/binaries are in this directory:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin

# ls -al /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin
total 120544
drwxrwxr-x  18 eric  admin       612 25 Jul 10:14 .
drwxrwxr-x   8 eric  admin       272 12 Jul 09:46 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 eric  admin   1705349 14 Jul 19:40 composer
lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  admin         8 25 Jul 10:14 composer.phar -> composer
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin       942  9 Dec  2015 pear
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin       963  9 Dec  2015 peardev
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin       879  9 Dec  2015 pecl
lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  admin         9 15 Dec  2015 phar -> phar.phar
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin     14854  9 Dec  2015 phar.phar
-rwxr-xr-x   1 eric  admin       797 25 Jul 09:12 phing
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin  18944064  9 Dec  2015 php
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin  18850440  9 Dec  2015 php-cgi
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin      4126  9 Dec  2015 php-config
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin  19149192  9 Dec  2015 phpdbg
-rwxrwxr-x   1 eric  admin      4627  9 Dec  2015 phpize
lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  admin        12 13 Jul 23:29 phpunit -> phpunit.phar
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 eric  staff   2988429 13 Jul 23:28 phpunit.phar
```

The result of running phing is:

```
# phing
Buildfile: /Users/eric/Development/php/phpstorm/my-awesome-app/build.xml

my-awesome-app > build:

 [composer] executing /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php composer.phar install

BUILD FAILED
/Users/eric/Development/php/phpstorm/my-awesome-app/build.xml:4:8: Composer binary not found, path is "composer.phar"
Total time: 0.0980 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used exec declaration as a work around:

```
<exec command="composer install" />
```

This will use the system path to find the composer script/phar (I have linked composer to composer.phar and made it executable.

I won't mark this answer as the chosen answer as I believe the built in composer command should be able to work without having to specify the full path to composer.phar in the build file.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an empty php attribute to the composer tag, it should run correctly as long as composer is in your path.

```
<composer php="" composer="composer" command="install" />
```